# Gabb Plus sim card locked

Tags: sim-card, sim-unlocking, gabb

My Gabb phone's sim card got locked. It's my only phone, so I can't call or text any number. I don't know my PUK code, which it requires to unlock. How would I unlock it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact you mobile network provider, that is the only way.

Comment: @Robert thanks! I got my PUK and it is all fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your service provider and it should work.

Or, you can look at the sim card box (if you got one) and it will say.